# How can I store 1byte value in 64bit register only using 64bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I need to write a pixelization assembly code  ONLY using %rax, %rbx, %rcx, %rdx, %rsi, and %rdi (also %rsp and %rbp)

So I've first wrote code in C and changed any other registers into 64 bit registers, but at the point below when I change the register it gives Segmentation default

C code:

```
*temp = b;
*(temp + 1) = g;  
*(temp + 2) = r;
```

Assembly code By gcc:

```
movq    -48(%rbp), %rax  
movl    %eax, %edx
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax  
movb    %dl, (%rax)      
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax  
addq    $1, %rax
movq    -56(%rbp), %rdx  
movb    %dl, (%rax)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
addq    $2, %rax
movq    -64(%rbp), %rdx  
movb    %dl, (%rax)
```

Changed %dl to %rdx:

```
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
movzbq  (%rdx), %rbx
movq    %rbx, (%rax)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
addq    $1, %rax
movq    -56(%rbp), %rdx
movzbq  (%rdx), %rbx
movq    %rbx, (%rax)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
addq    $2, %rax
movq    -64(%rbp), %rdx
movzbq  (%rdx), %rbx
movq    %rbx, (%rax)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It is encouraged to turn on compiler optimization so the assembly output would be shorter, by the way.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do and why. Anyway, if you are only allowed to use 64 bit stores you will need a read-modify-write if you just want to update 3 bytes (and then you should make sure all 8 bytes are accessible).

Comment: There isn't really a way to get rid of `movb %dl, (%rax)`.  I'm not sure what the point of this exercise is.  Maybe you misunderstood it.

Comment: @user202729 it's because professor doesn't want us to just converting c code but code with assembly language. So available registers are restricted :/

Comment: You can't store 1 byte value with 64b register store. (you can modify only one byte by reading other 7 bytes first and modifying only one, but write will be 8 bytes in any case) Also your question makes little sense, the C->asm didn't use optimizations, etc... sounds too much like Problem XY case. (edit: if this is about "pixels", those are usually a continuous array, so you should just pad it enough to allow for 8 byte writes overwriting a bit beyond, and process 8 bytes at same time, to store only once per 8 values). That actually makes sense also from performance point of view.

Comment: @SeokyoungKook Which registers can be used?

Comment: @user202729 %rax, %rbx, %rcx, %rdx, %rsi, and %rdi (also %rsp and %rbp)

Comment: @SeokyoungKook Then edit the question to specify that only those (64-bit) registers can be used. // Also what is `temp`, and are the memory at positions `*(temp+3)`, `*(temp+4)` etc. accessible?

Comment: @fuz professor told us to try >> %rax, %rbx, %rcx, %rdx, %rsi, and %rdi (also %rsp and %rbp)

Comment: if you need to process 8 bit values, but in 64b groups, you will have to think about it on higher level, like the whole loop processing all values. The way you are asking is not possible at all, or in very ineffective way (having temporary buffer `char temp[8+3];` or even more) and then processing the 3 bytes of `temp` later, wasting many machine cycles writing lot more memory than needed.

Comment: `%dl` is the low byte of `%rdx`.  Are you sure your professor wasn't just telling you to avoid RBX (which is call-preserved in the x86-64 System V calling convention), and R8..R15?

Comment: @Ped7g I think I need to rebuild everything from beginning considering your comment... was to naive :/ It only has been a month learning assembly code and normally I don't know I what I'm doing haha

Comment: @PeterCordes Sadly no :/ not even %eax, %ax, %al and any other are allowed. If we want to read 1 byte from memory, I should try >>movzbq (%rdi), %rax

Comment: Ok, then any byte manipulation you do will have to be with AND masks, shifts, and OR.  Or with `movzbq` loads from memory.  But you won't be able to do narrow stores.  (You could read/modify/write a qword and merge in a new byte, but that's pretty horribly slow.  If you have multiple adjacent byte-stores to do, combine them in a register first and do one store.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
 t = r & 0xff;
 u = *temp & ~ 0xfful;
 *temp = u | t;
 t = (g & 0xff) << 8;
 u = *temp & ~ 0xff00ul;
 *temp = u | t;
 t  = (b & 0xff) << 16; 
 u = *temp & ~0xff00000ull;
 *temp = u | t;
```

You should be able to write this with 64bit regs only.  You should also be able to find a whole bunch of ways to make this way smaller than this.